# Issue Glassfish 4 doesn't appear glassfish-web

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

I'm trying to create a descriptor file for my Java web application project.
For this project i am using:

```
Netbeans 8.0 &
GlassFish 4
```

When I try to create the glassfish descriptor file. Netbeans shows into the dialog window that is going to create a file called sun-web.xml instead of glassfish-web.xml.

I was looking for this on the internet and found that the first one sun-web.xml is created for version older than 3, and the version 4 should create a file with the name glassfish-web.xml.

I'm following a tutorial where a person is using the same tools that I have. But in the tutorial he can create a glassfish-web.xml file.

Another error raise when I click the finish button with the intention of create the sun-web.xml file and an error popup raise a show me this message:

"Deployment Configuration for this project not found. Deployment descriptor version could not be set properly"

Can't anyone help me please ???

Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Same problem here. Reinstalling Glassfish 4 did not work.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use that sun-web.xml file fine, it might change in a couple of ways like for example when you want to add a security role mapping, NetBeans won't be able to automatically fill in the security role names from your web.xml, but if you fill them in manually and correctly you should be fine.

Actually, I had the same problem, so what I did was erase all versions of Glassfish (I use OSX so I erased the folders from Applications > Netbeans > GlassFish and from Users/MyUser/GlassFish_Server), added a new server in NetBeans Services > Servers > right click add server and follow the wizard, when you get to step 2 (Server location) click download now and that will reinstall glassfish, restart NetBeans and now when you try to create a Glassfish descriptor it should be properly named as glass fish-web.xml

Hope this helps :)

Comment: sun-web.xml has been replace with glassfish-web.xml, however.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed version Java EE 7 to Java EE 5 when creating new project at 3rd step **Server and Settings** and it could create glassfish-web.xml. I'm using same versions of Netbeans and Glasssfish. Hope may this will help you.
[image: Change Java E Version]